# Can't find url in webLogic deployment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, weblogic

Tis is my first time deploying with weblogic, I have a spring boot application and when i add in weblogic than I can't find the path for my rest call, in my main application I even added this log to see where is running but i get no output:

```
 private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KpiApplication.class);
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
      SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(KpiApplication.class);
      Environment env = app.run(args).getEnvironment();
      String protocol = "http";
      if (env.getProperty("server.ssl.key-store") != null) {
          protocol = "https";
      }
      System.out.println("LEXA"+ env.getProperty("server.port")+InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
      try {
        LOGGER.info("\n----------------------------------------------------------\n\t" +
                    "Application '{}' is running! Access URLs:\n\t" +
                    "Local: \t\t{}://localhost:{}\n\t" +
                    "External: \t{}://{}:{}\n\t" +
                    "Profile(s): \t{}\n----------------------------------------------------------",
                  env.getProperty("spring.application.name"),
                  protocol,
                  env.getProperty("server.port"),
                  protocol,
                  InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(),
                  env.getProperty("server.port"),
                  env.getActiveProfiles());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SpringApplication.run(KpiApplication.class);
}
```

}

In my weblogic i see this path in this section but i just says page not found:
[image: web]

The rest I'm trying to execute is this but everytime is a page not found:

```
@RestController
public class AccountController extends KpiAbstractController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @GetMapping("/v1/accounts")
    public ResponseEntity<AccountDTO> getAccounts(@RequestParam @ApiParam("Point of sale owner ID") String ownerPosId,
                                                  @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate startPeriod,
                                                  @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate endPeriod,
                                                  HttpServletRequest request)
```

All the application is already setted up and my manager just told me try it, but he doesn't know the link too, any idea where I can find it please

Answer (score 0):

Have you done what's written in Spring Boot docs "traditional deployment" part? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.traditional-deployment
Looks like, you didn't.
You get no output from your logs, because `public static void main` will not be called on WebLogic - you will need to extend SpringBootServletInitializer instead.

Also for weblogic you would usually create src/main/webapp/weblogic.xml file where you would set context-root, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.5/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <context-root>myapp</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Which make you application accessible at `http://server:port/myapp` URL.

Another thing you didn't mention is if you have a sole AdminServer or AdminServer+ManagedServer? If the letter, then you should deploy your application via AdminServer to ManagedServer and access it at ManagedServer host:port.